# Is there a way to turn a list of lists into a list with no other lists in it in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of lists.

```py
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, [9, 0]]]
```

Is there a way to take all the items from that list and make it a single, un-nested list?
Something like this:

```py
>>> break_up(my_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses recursion

```
def appnd(new_list = [], list_to_append=[]):
    for i in list_to_append:
        if type(i) == list:
            appnd(new_list=new_list, list_to_append=i)
        else:
            new_list.append(i)

def main():
    my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, [9, 0]]]
    new_list = []
    appnd(new_list=new_list, list_to_append=my_list)
    print(new_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```